# Connect TFS 2017 create external TFS connection for TFS 2013

Tags: http-status-code-401

How can I add an external TFS Connection to TFS 2017 to allow it to connect to TFS 2013?

I navigated to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collection/team_project_name/_admin/_services?_a=resources and clicked `New Service Endpoint`. I selected `External TFS`

[image]

When I go to verify the connection after entering all the relevant information, I get the below error.

```
Failed to query service endpoint api: http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collection/_apis/projects. Error Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized..
```

Here is a screenshot of the error.

[image]

The odd thing is that if I make a GET request to http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collection/_apis/projects without any authentication I get a 200 OK response back with project information.

I have configured basic authentication per the [tfs cli guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md). How can I verify that basic authentication is configured correctly? When I try to login with tfx, I get the following screen.

[image: tfx from command prompt]

I have the following extensions installed on the TFS 2017 instance.

- Package Management
- Release Management Utility tasks
- TFS artifacts for Release Management

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 15.105.25910.0

Comment: Where did you add this  in TFS 2017? Looks like you are adding a service endpoint , however I couldn't find this in the default service endpoint list. Did you install some extension? Moreover, what' the detail version of your TFS2017 ? Are you using [TFS 2017 update1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update1)?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT what's the best place to find the detail version for my TFS 2017?

Comment: On the right top of the home page click"..." then click **about**, you will get the detail version. Sample screenshot have updated in your question. How did you open the dialog above? Did you just add a service?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I updated the question with the information that you had mentioned. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: You need to check two things basic authentication, username format. Details please refer my reply below.

Comment: @RyanGates Have you tried updating the TFS Collection URL you entered to "http://xxx:8080/tfs/collectionname" instead of "http://xxx:8080/tfs/_home"?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I did try it with http://xxx:8080/tfs/collectionname%22, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, you are using [TFS artifacts for Release Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs) extension to connect to another TFS instance.

Make sure the things below:

1. Make sure the collection URL you enter is correct. In your screenshot, the URL you enter is ended with "_home".
2. Make sure [Basic Auth](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md) is enabled on TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using the extension **TFS artifacts for Release Management** which provides a service endpoint to connect to an external TFS or VS Team Services Collection.

After test with TFS2013, I could reproduce your issue and got the same error information. The solution please see below:

- Since you are connecting to TFS2013, it works with **basic
  authentication** only. You’ll need to [enable basic authentication
  support](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/configureBasicAuth.md) for the TFS Server which handling TFS2013.
- Also please make sure the **username** to connect to the **external TFS
  collection** are **with Domain in front of**. Then will get a green
  verfifed status.

[image]

Comment: I got the same result when I used the username format `DOMAIN\USER`. I updated the question with a screenshot of what I get when trying to use tfx directly.

Comment: @RyanGates After following the guide, the basic authentication should be configured already. TFX is another tool ,nothing to do with our case. Add the link just cause there is a detailed introduction of how to enable basic authentication in GitHub. Please give a  try  with enable  basic authentication both on your server TFS2017 & 2013. And also make sure your account could be able to login in the collection on TFS 2013(such as enough permission). Also double check the firewall settings,  both servers can ping successful and in the trust list  each other.

Comment: I was trying to use TFX to verify that I had the basic authentication configured correctly. I am still getting the error after installing/enabling basic authentication on both. I was able to make the request from powershell on the TFS 2017 server. It was `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/collection/_apis/projects" -Credential DOMAIN\User`.

Comment: Have no idea why you still get this error. Are you using the same domain account to connect your TFS 2017/TFS2013? You could try this in your VS to connect the collection. Also suggest you to submit your issue in the comment of extension page: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs which  the owner of  the extension will listen your voice.

Comment: @RyanGates sorry please see the above comment, forget to @ you

Comment: I did notice that the TFS 2013 instance and TFS 2017 instance are running under different service accounts. I'm trying to make them the same, but I have to get the credentials for that account. I will let you know if that changes anything.